# Transfer learning for industrial AOI use case

Tags: transfer-learning, pre-trained-model, conv-neural-network

At the moment I'm working on an industrial automatic optical inspection use case where I try different kinds of pretrained CNNs like MobileNet, Resnet, VGGNet or InceptionV3, all pretrained with Imagenet.

I'm wondering if you could give me an advice which model is most suitable for an industrial AOI use case where the aim is to find defects on material surface. The images are gray scale.

Do you think a pretrained model makes more sense here (in case yes - which model? only train the newly added dense layer(s) or also retrain the conv layers?) or do you think it is in such a case more senseful to develop and train a CNN from scratch?
Maybe someone has some experience and can share it!
Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

My company use VGG model to classifier the real defect and
fake defect.

But we will use traditional picture process before the deeplearning usded.